# Mysqli "IN" Operator Dynamic and Static values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Actually I am trying to get results from a column where id is 219 and where id is match with a query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE `id` IN ('219', SELECT `id` FROM `table2` WHERE `parent_id`='219')
```

I want to use id 219 and query together so the query will pull up some more ids. but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this version:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id = 219 OR id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE parent_id = 219);
```

Your question has the flavor of a recursive hierarchical query, where we would probably be doing some sort of join.  If you need more complicated output, then you should update your question.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, `OR` clause was not well optimized in `MySQL`. Another option, make a subquery under `IN` clause to include '219' also like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE parent_id = 219 UNION SELECT '219')
```